# convert date(yyyy-mm-dd) to yyyy MMM dd javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have following code

```
startDate = "2012-08-12"
```

I am subtracting 30 days from that date

```
var date = new Date(startDate);
var newDate = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 30);
```

I want to convert that newDate in the format `yyyy MMM dd` `2012 JUL 11` (subtracting 30 days from the date)

**EDIT**

I don't want to use any plugins

I have been trying a long method to extract date, month and year and an array of months then substituting it.

Comment: Have you tried DateJS?  (www.datejs.com)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: @AresAvatar, I can't use the plugins, its pain to go through legal department to get it approved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this as following:

```
myDate= Date.parse("2012-08-12") - 2592000000;
newDate = new Date(myDate);
```

Just parse the date so you get a number

Comment: Umm...wouldn't that subtract 30 milliseconds?

Comment: No, to account for DST. Use UTC to create a new date object ie: Date.UTC("...") see the difference here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110039/javascript-dates-what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-daylight-savings-time