# Adding a week to Date in JavaScript: rounding error or daylight savings?

Tags: javascript, date, rounding, dst

I am trying to add seven days to a Data object, however at some stage I start getting strange results.

```
var currDate = new Date(2011, 2, 28)
  , oldTicks = currDate.getTime()
  , newTicks = oldTicks + (86400000 * 7)
  , nextWeek = new Date(newTicks)
console.log('Old ticks: ' + oldTicks)
console.log('New ticks: ' + newTicks)
console.log('New date : ' + nextWeek)
```

The output I get, both Chrome/FF is:

```
Old ticks: 1301230800000
New ticks: 1301835600000
log: New date : Sun Apr 03 2011 23:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)
```

Expected to get:

```
log: New date : Mon Apr 04 2011 23:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)
```

As you can see, instead of adding 7 days, just 6 were added. The code above, however, works fine with other dates, say 2011 Apr 28 or 2011 May 28.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109641/javascript-date-is-this-my-error-or-did-i-find-a-bug

Comment: @Crescent Fresh - daylight savings ends 13 Mar 2011, so I don't see how that could possibly have anything to do with this.

Comment: There's no way it can be a "rounding error" because all those numbers fit comfortably in a 32-bit integer, let alone a double-precision floating point value.

Comment: The only countries that are at GMT+1000 are Caroline Islands, and Papua New Guinea, neither of which follow daylight savings. Can you also log `currDate` for us?

Comment: What time zone is that?  Also, what happens when you print the formatted date string from "currDate"?

Comment: I would assume EST stands for Eastern Time zone which should be -5 not +10 from UTC

Comment: @Pointy: parts of Australia [still observe Daylight Savings](http://australia.gov.au/about-australia/our-country/time), which ends Apr 3rd.

Comment: Ah well durr I guess maybe everybody *should* get to decide their own daylight savings schedule :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crescent Fresh is correct  form what I can deduce.
Looking up timezones `GMT+1000 (EST)` looks like Australia Eastern Standard Time - from [wikipedia - list of timezones by UTC offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zones_by_UTC_offset)

And from [wikipedia - daylist savings time around the world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_around_the_world#Australia), shows that Australia switches from standard to daylight savings time in between the date ranges specified by the OP.

Comment: I wonder why it is only applicable when adding milliseconds, but not days as in new Date(curDate.getFullYear(), curDate.getMonth(), curDate.getDate() + 7)

Comment: @Art: it is applicable because you are adding milliseconds manually to the result of `getTime()`. That's just arithmetic. If you were to use the Date constructor as `new Date(curDate.getFullYear(), curDate.getMonth(), curDate.getDate(), curDate.getHours(), curDate.getMinutes(), curDate.getSeconds(), curDate.getMilliseconds()+ 86400000 * 7)`, it would also work.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me I'd do:

```
var curDate = new Date(),

var aWeekLater = new Date(curDate.getFullYear(), curDate.getMonth(), curDate.getDate() + 7);
```

with some possible adjustments for time of day.

That said, when I try your code in my Chrome developer console, I get 04 Apr as the answer.